# Why instantiate a new list before recursion call?

Tags: java

```
public void dfsSearch (TreeNode root, List<String> curr, List<List<String>> res) {
        curr.add(String.valueOf(root.val));
        // a leaf node has been reached
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            res.add(curr);
            return;
        }
        if (root.left != null) {
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(curr);
            dfsSearch(root.left, temp, res);
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(curr);
            dfsSearch(root.right, temp, res);
        }
    }
```

The code above is a a method using dfs to find all the paths from root to leaves in a binary tree, and my question is, in the two lines above the recursive call, why do I need to instantiate a new list and pass this temp list (temp) to the recursive call, why can't I just use the curr (the argument in the function)?

Comment: To make this question clear, before each recursion call, why need to use a new list, temp here, and can't use curr instead?

Comment: Because curr is being modified recursively. Imagine you go down the left side of a binary tree (which is what you'll do in DFS). You hit a leaf, thus curr has the path to the first leaf. Then when you pop from the recursive stack, if you use the same curr, you will go to the right and add the right child node, thus curr incorrectly has the leaf from the previous recursive call and now has the right child.

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that List is a reference type. Wich means that when you pass your `curr` list as a parameter, it doesn't create a new object for the new method being called. It is the same object the calling method has, that's why you don't create a temp List for the `res` list, you want to modify the same list in all your recursive calls

Comment: Got it, Thanks, reference type, if here is a integer, it's no matter create a new int or not, right?

Comment: hmm if you mean an **int** (primitive type, same as char, boolean, short, etc.) then yes. It will pass only the value, not the reference to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this is your binary tree

```
     1
   2    3
  4 5
```

Let's say you didn't use `temp`. Then you would recurse down the left side of the binary tree, meaning curr would add 1,2,and 4. Because lists are mutable, their values are saved in recursive calls, even when you pop from the recursive stack. So after adding 4 to curr, you will go back to node 2, go to the right, and add 5. Thus curr will contain 1,2,4,5 instead of what you want, 1,2,4 and 1,2,5.

Comment: got it, just like Freddy Hdz said, List in java is a reference type, if I don't create a new list, I will end up using the same curr for called and calling method, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The copies are to prevent concurrent modification of `curr` when the `dfsSearch` method is called recursively. The first line `curr.add(String.valueOf(root.val));` modifies the `curr` collection, and you can't loop through a collection while modifying it.

Comment: How do you know this method is being called concurrently?

Comment: The recursion itself is the source of the concurrency. While the outer/parent call to `dfsSearch` is in the middle of executing, but has not yet exited its block, the inner/child call to `dfsSearch` executes and bam!

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent Modification is one reason.  But additionally, the algorithm collects "all paths" from root to leaves in the List of Lists result.  If you didn't create new lists at each level on the recursive way down, you would end up with one big jumbled list after the recursion bubbles back up (all paths from root to leaves collected in one mixed list instead of each path in its own list).